# CSS: Is it possible to get a div that is 100% height, less a top and bottom margin?

Tags: html, css

I can get a 100% height div, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>T5</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.0.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css">
    </link>

    <style type="text/css">
      * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
      html, body { height: 100%; }
      body {
         font-family: "lucida sans", verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
         font-size: 75%;
      }
      h1 { font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.4em; padding: 10px 10px 0;}
      p { padding: 0 10px 1em; }
      #container {
         min-height: 100%;
         background-color: #DDD;
         border-left: 2px solid #666;
         border-right: 2px solid #666;
         width: 280px;
         margin: 0 auto;
      }
      * html #container { height: 100%; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <h1>100% Height Div</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

When I say "100% height" - I mean it stays full height regardless of how much content is in the div, and regardless of how the window gets resized.

But is it possible to get a div with a height of "almost 100%" height?  If I want margins at the top and bottom, can I do that?

I want it to look like this:

[image]

I can do this with Javascript+CSS.  Can I do it with just CSS?

---

**Answer:**
Yes, it's possible with absolute positioning.

```
  #container {
     width: 380px;
     background-color: #DDD;
     border: 2px solid #666;
     position: absolute;
     top: 20px;    /* margin from top */
     bottom: 20px; /* margin from bottom */
     left: 50%;    /* start left side in middle of window */
     margin-left: -190px; /* then, reverse indent */
     overflow: auto; /* scrollbar as necessary */
  }
```

Result:

[image]

Thanks [to keithjgrant for the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496260/css-is-it-possible-to-get-a-div-that-is-100-height-less-a-top-and-bottom-marg/2501296#2501296). See all the code at http://jsbin.com/otobi .

Comment: Can't this be done by adding _padding:20px 0 20px 0;_ to the #container id style?

Comment: No, because padding and margin are added to the height/width. So this would make a 100%+40px height.

Comment: you need to create an inner-container inside your container and then add the padding to that

Comment: @stephen murdoch: So you say. show me.

Comment: looks like you have a better solution below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try absolute positioning:

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

It can be quirky in IE6 (what isn't?), but there are a lot of tricks to try if you google around.  Some include adding a `clear: both` rule or wrapping your absolute-positioned div inside another div.

An `overflow: auto` should make the scrollbar behave as you have it pictured.

**edit:**  Alternately, you could add 20px padding to a wrapper div, then set your container to `height: 100%` with no margin, and it should fill up to the padding of its wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I missed something, but why not add `margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px` to `#container`, if you want margins?

Comment: @poke wrote: "No, because padding and margin are added to the height/width. So this would make a 100%+40px height."

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1) You can use something like

```
#theDiv {
    top: 16px;
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

but this will only work on standards compliant browsers and IE >= 7, as IE 6 will not render your div correctly when using both `top` *and* `bottom`.

2) You can change the [box model](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html) to include borders at top and bottom **within** a given `height`. Use something like

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -khtml-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box; /* IE >= 8 */
}
```

so you can fake `top` and `bottom` using

```
#theDiv {
    border-top: 16px;
    border-bottom: 20px;
}
```

and put IE 6 and 7 in quirks mode (by putting something, e.g. an HTML comment, before the DOCTYPE) to use `border-box` box model.

If you want to support IE 6, you'll have to use #2. So in IE 6 you can only use quirks mode when you want this (the only other option to support this in IE 6 is using CSS expressions, but they are very CPU intensive, as the J(ava)Script engine of IE must recalculate those widths and heights on every resize).

Comment: Does MS actually support `-ms-box-sizing`? I know that `-ms-box-radius` doesn't even work in IE8.

Comment: @TheEl: According to the linked page (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html), yes, and according to this (stupidly designed) PDF http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/F/E/FFEB6B00-64B9-450F-93B3-2781D9F36210/BoxSizing-DeveloperSeriesInformationPage.pdf, IE 8 supports both `box-sizing` and `-ms-box-sizing`.

Answer (score 0):

Its not precise like CSS but you could just add a BR tag outside the container at the top and bottom and adjust your 100% min margin to like 90-95%.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a second div inside with a padding to realize the actual "outer" padding:

```
<div style="height: 100%; width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; background: #CCC; border: solid #999; border-width: 0px 2px;">
 <div style="padding: 20px 0px;">
  Content here
 </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you don't display anything else, you can also use the `body` for the outer construction.

**edit:** Actually, you'll have to use `min-height` for the outer div, to keep the background working when your page is higher than 100% of the screen size. This for example works fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
 <title>Test</title>
 <style type="text/css">
   html
   { height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; background: #FFF; }
   body
   { min-height: 100%; margin: auto; width: 500px;
     background: #CCC; border: solid #999; border-width: 0 2px; }
   div#main
   { padding: 20px 15px; }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">
 <h1>100% Height Div</h1>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo
  ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
  parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec,
  pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec
  pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo,
  rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
 <p>Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
  Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo
  ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante,
  dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus
  varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel
  augue.</p> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this work on IE6? Anyway, does @Cheeso want to support IE6?

Comment: Iirc, IE6 doesn't support `min-height`, but I doubt there is any other method that would make this work (without using javascript of course). Every later browser does support it though.