# Center the page around a div

Tags: jquery

I want to center a div in the document body in jquery.

I have a read more button that shows an extra div when you click it, and i want the move the window position to be centered around this div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [ScrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) plugin.  If memory serves correctly, it scrolls using the scrollbars so you don't take a massive performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[CSS: Is it possible to get a div that is 100% height, less a top and bottom margin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496260/css-is-it-possible-to-get-a-div-that-is-100-height-less-a-top-and-bottom-marg)

[image]

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think he has dynamic content he wants to focus on based on a user click.